# Why won't scikit-image work for Python3?

Tags: software-installation, python, colors, image-processing

So I'm trying to use scikit-image for several functions on images. One such function is converting an image from rgb to hsv where I took my image (img) and said

```
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
img_hsv = color.rgb2hsv(img)
```

Python didn't seem to have a problem recognizing the skimage statements when importing it but when I call color.rgb2hsv I get an error that says `'color' is not defined`. If I just say `img_hsv = rgb2hsv` then it says `'rgb2hsv' is not defined`. I tried to install scikit-image by cloning it from github and following these instructions. 
http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html 
For some reason, whenever I get to the part where I have to say `pip install -e .`, it says `python 2.7 discovered. You must install scikit-image lower than 0.15.` but I do have Python 3.6 so I should be able to install it for 3.6 but for some reason, Linux isn't letting me install it no matter what I do. So what exactly can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip installs the latest stable versions of Python packages by default. What's wrong with installing the latest stable version with `pip install scikit-image` instead of cloning it from GitHub? The latest stable version of scikit-image (Image processing routines for SciPy) is 0.14.2.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip  
sudo pip3 install scikit-image
```

If numpy, scipy, pillow and matplotlib are not already installed the above command will also install those packages as dependencies.

btw You got an error that says `NameError: name 'color' is not defined` because you forgot to import color from skimage.

Comment: I tried that and it's not working. it says that everything is installed correctly but for some really strange reason it keeps saying that names like 'color' and 'rgb2hsv' are not defined even though I clearly imported them. It keeps saying scikit-image is properly installed so do you think it's a problem with my python code?

Comment: It's possible that there is a problem with the Python code, but debugging the code is out of scope for Ask Ubuntu, but on topic at Stack Overflow. Nonetheless if you copy/paste the code to [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/), and provide a link to the pastebin in a comment, I will try running it, and see what happens. I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dCgNPjK6FN/

Comment: There is an error in your Python code. After the line in your code that says `import colorsys` add a new line that says `from skimage import color` and then the next line after that is `from skimage.color import rgb2hsv` as before. You see the error is that you forgot to import color. Do this and your Python code will run successfully. I am using Python 3.6.